# How to use seqinr::computePI on a list of character vectors

Tags: r, strsplit

This is what the input data looks like (representative sample).

```r
sample1        MAQSVNIQDQYLNQ
sample2        MAADRAQNLQDTFLNHV
sample3        MAERSQNLQ
```

I am trying to use the `computePI()` function from the `seqinr` library to perform a calculation on the second column. To do this, I need to convert the character strings in the second column to a vector of single characters, and use that as input for `computePI()`. To do this, I tried using `strsplit()`. It works on an individual string:

```r
library(seqinr)
str <- c("MAQSVNIQDQYLNQ")
unlist(strsplit(str, split = ""))
#R> [1] "M" "A" "Q" "S" "V" "N" "I" "Q" "D" "Q" "Y" "L" "N" "Q"
```

Followed by:

```r
computePI(unlist(strsplit(str, split = "")))
#R> [1] 3.799404
```

After saving the input data read using `read.csv` to a variable:

```r
data <- read.csv("filename", header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

I tried the following:

```r
computePI(unlist(strsplit(data$V2, split = "")))
```

But got an error telling me that the input isn't a character string. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply` :

```
sapply(strsplit(data$V2, split = ""), seqinr::computePI)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vectorize`:

```r
library(seqinr)
VcomputePI <- Vectorize(computePI)
VcomputePI(strsplit(dat$V2, split = ""))
#R> [1] 3.799404 5.194135 5.753213
```

Or `sapply`/`lapply`/`vapply` like as [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64457957/5861244) shows. `vapply` is likely the fastest:

```r
vapply(strsplit(dat$V2, split = ""), computePI, 0.)
#R> [1] 3.799404 5.194135 5.753213
```

#### Data

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = paste0("sample", 1:3), 
  V2 = c("MAQSVNIQDQYLNQ", "MAADRAQNLQDTFLNHV", "MAERSQNLQ"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```